# Sum of three normal distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Whether the sum of three normal distributed random variables can be nontrivial and discountinuous distributied or not, for example, Bernoulli, Poisson, or binomial distributied?

If they are independent or have joint normal distribution, the distribution of the sum is normal distribution. But if they are dependent and have no joint normal distribution, the distribution of the sum may be nontrivial and discontinous.

Is there any example?

Comment: Are they assumed independent or not?

Comment: If they are not independent, then the sum can be just about _anything_. Consider $Y=X, Z=1-X-Y$.